# flutter pub get won't download dependency

Tags: flutter, dependencies

I deleted a package manually from `Dart Package` directory and deleted `pubspec.lock`. Now when I do `flutter pub get` it does not download that package again. I tried `flutter clean` && `flutter pub get` but it's not working as well. Please help I can't build my project now.

Comment: any outputs when running `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: No it's run fine. but do not download that package again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to close and then open the editor and try:

```
flutter clean

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade
```

Comment: thanks I deleted pub_cache folder and redownloded all packages.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't do anything, and based on the comment of u_s_e_r, the actual fix is: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache

```
dart pub cache repair
```

This worked in my case